# how can i delete files according to size and date in a folder

Tags: asp.net, directory

Suppose i have 4 files in a folder
2 file for yesterday
1 file- 1 mb
2nn file- 2mb
2 file for today
1st file-5 mb
2nd file- 10 mb

first i want to check date for each file and according to that file we check size 
file with minimum will be deleted from the folder

in my code i delete all file with minimum size but i want to delete file which have mini size day wise

here is my code:

```
 private void DeleteFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\test");
        var files = di.GetFiles();
        var maxFile = files.Max(r => r.Length);

        foreach (FileInfo file in files.Where(r => r.Length < maxFile))
        {
            file.Delete();
        }   
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DeleteFiles();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
private void DeleteFiles()
{
  var di = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\test");
  var files = di.GetFiles().GroupBy(f => f.LastWriteTime.Date);

  foreach (var fileGrp in files)
  {
    var maxFile = fileGrp.Max(r => r.Length);

    foreach (FileInfo file in fileGrp.Where(r => r.Length < maxFile))
    {
      file.Delete();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) groups the files according to the specified parameter, in this case the date. Then for each group (date) retrieve the largest file size and then delete all the smaller files.

Comment: u dere?
i have one more question in that which just come across my mind can u answer that to